# Boolean algebra proof - I don't know why this is valid!

Tags: logic, proof-writing, boolean-algebra

So this is the answer proof I was given, I'm stumped by the final application of the Idempotent law (where does that 1 come from!?)

As I understood it a 0 or 1 can only come from a combination of A and not A

```
R = (A + C) • (A • D + A • D') + A • C + C
R = (A + C) • (A • (D + D')) + A • C + C Distributive Rule
= (A + C) • A + A • C + C Negation Rule
= A • A + C • A + A • C + C Distributive Rule
= A + A • C + C Idempotent Rule
= A • (1 + C) + C Distributive Rule
= A + C Simplification Rule
```

Comment: The idempotent rules are $X \cdot X = X$ or $X + X = X$.  Both versions, as well as commutativity, are used to arrive at the fifth line: $A \cdot A$ is replaced by $A$, $C \cdot A$ is replaced by $A \cdot C$, and $(A \cdot C) + (A \cdot C)$ is replaced by a single $A \cdot C$.

Comment: The sixth line is produced using the *distributive* law: $A = A \cdot 1$, and then $(A \cdot 1) + (A \cdot C)$ is replaced by $A \cdot (1 + C)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$A+A\cdot C = A\cdot 1 + A\cdot C = A\cdot(1+C) $$
since $A\cdot 1=A$, and you're free to use identities "in reverse".